# How to prove location scale transformation of a distribution preserves a distribution?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

If I do a location scale transformation on a distribution, how can I prove that the transformed distribution still belongs to the same family of distributions? I know that we can do location scale transformation on normal and other distributions, but I'm not sure how to prove the transformed distribution still belongs to the original family.

Any explanations would be really helpful.

Comment: It seems there's really nothing to "prove": it comes down to the definition of the family.  Do you have a specific example in mind that could illustrate the content of your question?

Comment: Suppose I start with the standard Normal and then apply location scale transformation, how can I verify the transformed distribution is also normal?

Comment: Note that if you start with - for example - a (usual) two-parameter F-distribution, a location shift doesn't leave you with another F-distribution

Comment: @Glen_b that is the precise reason why I need to know how to determine if the transformation stays within the same family for a distribution

Comment: Do you mean to ask "how can I tell if a family of distributions is a [location-scale family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family)?"

Comment: @Glen_b no, I meant when I do a location scale transformation how can I tell whether the PDF I get is still within the family, i.e if I do a location scale transformation of a standard Normal, how can I know that the transformed PDF is still within the same family?

Comment: There are two aspects of this question. (1) How does a location-scale transformation affect the way in which you represent a distribution? (2) How can you tell whether a particular expression for a distribution is a member of a family?  Both of these depend on (a) how you are representing distributions--are you using their CDF, PDF (or PMF), CF, CGF, Survival Function, Hazard Function, or something else?--and (b) how are you defining the family--in terms of basic properties (such as a set of entropy-minimizing distributions), parametric formulas for a CDF, PDF, etc., or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is a usual trick to prove that the transformed distribution is still Normal, which is showing that its Moment Generating Function (/Fourier Transf) is that of a normal. There might be other less computational ways, of course, but this one is the textbook way.

Comment: I think the question is more general and needs clarification.  The normal was used as a simple example.